# Use conditions in calculated column in sharepoint 2013

Tags: calculated-column, conditional

I want to make a formula in my calculated column in this meaning please:

```
if (Column1 !=null && Column2 !=null && Column3 !=null)
```

Display Approved else let it empty

Comment: Can you try this please `=IF(LEN(Column1)>0,IF(LEN(Column2)>0,IF(LEN(Column3)>0,"Approved",""),""),"")`

Comment: Yes it work Arslan thnx :)

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
=IF(LEN(Column1)>0,IF(LEN(Column2)>0,IF(LEN(Column3)>0,"Approved",""),""),"")
```